# Невозможно найти исполняемый файл компилятора csc.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, компиляция

Среда разработки Visual Studio 2019, язык С#, .NET Framework v4.7.2. Пытаюсь скомпилировать простой код, который должен скомпилировать новый файл в ходе работы программы. Код взят отсюда - https://habr.com/ru/post/67431/. При компиляции возникает исключение `Невозможно найти исполняемый файл компилятора csc.exe` в строке `CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);`. В сети есть решения этой проблемы, но для других ситуаций, а у меня ошибка возникает в простом примере кода.

Вот весь код:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace ConsoleCompile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Source code для компиляции
            string source =
            @"
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        public static void SayHello()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello World"");
            System.Console.WriteLine( string.Join("","", Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(n=>n.ToString()).ToArray() ) );
        }
    }
}
            ";

            // Настройки компиляции 
            Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"CompilerVersion", "v4.7.2"}
                };
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);

            CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
            { OutputAssembly = "D:\\Foo.EXE", GenerateExecutable = true };

            // Компиляция 
            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);

            // Выводим информацию об ошибках 
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Errors: {0}", results.Errors.Count);
            foreach (CompilerError err in results.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR {0}", err.ErrorText);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм, может, у вас Студия как-то странно установилась? Попробуйте ради интереса на другой машине.

Comment: 4.7.2 - это версия фреймворка. Я так понимаю, версия компилятора должна быть 4.0. В словаре задайте `"CompilerVersion", "v4.0"`. / https://stackoverflow.com/a/46995130/5045688 - чёрт ногу сломит в этих версиях. Возможно, v4.7 сработает

Comment: "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" - это помогло, спасибо

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Оформите как ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы используете .NET Framework 4.7.2, очевидно поэтому в коде задали значение "v4.7.2". Но это версия фреймворка. Вам нужно указать версию компилятора.

В словаре задайте `"CompilerVersion", "v4.0"`.